# How do I validate this kind of xml errors in the c# code?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <a>str1234</a>xxxx
</xml>
```

I got this xml file, as you can see, there's "xxxx" after the "a" close tag.

I tried the `xmldocument.load()` method but it wouldn't throw any exceptions.

I tried to generate a xsd file from this xml, then validate this xml with the generated xsd.

However, it also wouldn't throw any errors.

Comment: "Probably" because this is valid xml ...

Comment: But when my code loading this kind of .config file,it got stuck.

Comment: are you going to serialize and get the output ? or what is your need? please specify clearly

Comment: ohhh k. this is a valid xml file. why it will show error?

Comment: Just to echo other comments, this is perfectly valid XML. You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having with it. What is *'the code loading this kind of .config file'* and what do you mean by *'it got stuck'*?

Comment: Commenters offering help should take care to [**use *valid* and *well-formed* properly**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134494/is-there-a-difference-between-valid-xml-and-well-formed-xml).  They have precise meanings that beginners should understand.  See that link and [**my answer below**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43157821/290085)  for details.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand the [difference between valid and well-formed XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

Commenters have sloppily said that your XML is *valid*.  They actually should not make such a statement without a schema against which to assess validity.  They should be saying that your XML is *well-formed*.

You seem to be concerned that `xxxx` text as a sibling to an `a` element is not well formed, but it is perfectly well-formed XML.  It might also be *valid*, if the parent element, `xml` is defined by a schema to allow *mixed-content*.

> I tried to generate a xsd file from this xml, then validate this xml
>   with the generated xsd.

Well, if you used a tool to generate an XSD from an XML document instance, and the XSD said the XML was valid, then the tool is working as designed.

> But when my code loading this kind of .config file,it got stuck.

Just like being well-formed doesn't guarantee validity, it also doesn't guarantee that it meets the needs of any given consuming XML application.  A configuration file has rules, perhaps expressed in an XSD, that the XML must follow.  These rules are in addition to being well-formed (the rules that a parser requires in order to parse XML).

See also [How to validate xml code file though .NET? + How would I do it if I use XML serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111747/how-to-validate-xml-code-file-though-net-how-would-i-do-it-if-i-use-xml-seri)

Comment: Great answer,dude.It solved my problem.All I need is to find out complextype is mixed or not.If it's mixed, it's not the right xml I want.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.